# Plotting isolated nodes in igraph with graph_from_data_frame. Missing

Tags: r, igraph

I'm working with data.frames with columns "from" and "to" and I would like to create network graphs from them.

For example:

```
mydata <- data.table(from=c("John", "John", "Jim", "Jesse"),
   to=c("John", "Jim", "Jack", NA))
mygraph <- graph_from_data_frame(d=mydata, directed=T)
plot(mygraph, vertex.label.dist=2)
```

The presence of that NA produces an error.

If I just remove the NA row the lonely node is not plotted.

```
mydata <- data.table(from=c("John", "John", "Jim"),to=c("John", "Jim", "Jack"))
mygraph <- graph_from_data_frame(d=mydata, directed=T)
plot(mygraph, vertex.label.dist=2)
```

[image]

I would like to get the same result than with:

```
g4 <- graph( c("John", "Jim", "Jim",  "Jack", "John", "John"), isolates=c("Jesse") )  
plot(g4,  vertex.label.dist=2)
```

[image]

but working with two columns, from and to.
How can I get the same result?
When any of the "from" or "to" is NA then just plot the node without edges and without producing errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673949/creating-igraph-with-isolated-nodes/42675086 is one approach. Another `tab <- table(lapply(mydata, factor, levels=na.omit(unique(unlist(mydata))))) ; g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(tab)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get what you want is to leave out the single node, but then add it using `add_vertices`

```
library(igraph)
mydata <- data.frame(from=c("John", "John", "Jim"),
   to=c("John", "Jim", "Jack"))
mygraph <- graph_from_data_frame(d=mydata, directed=T)
mygraph = add_vertices(mygraph, 1, name="Jesse")
plot(mygraph, vertex.label.dist=2)
```

[image]

Comment: OK, I'll try to automatize it for larger datasets and see if any problem arises

Comment: I think we will have a problem when the same node appear twice, as a single node and as a connected node.

Comment: I think that you are saying that you will get a list of "from" and "to nodes. Some will be NA.  You can scan the lists for NA to add those nodes separately,  but Some of those node may also be in the lists with connections. That is OK,  remove the ones that match an NA,  then use `setdiff` to remove any that are still on the two lists.